# Parsing struct with arrays with Boost Spirit

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, boost-spirit-qi

Before I start, yes I know there are a lot of post related to this topic, I spend more than a day reading but my knowledge about Boost::spirit is limited so I can figure out how solve my problem.

I take the Boost Employee example and modify it, let me show you

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <complex>

namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Our employee struct
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //[tutorial_employee_struct
struct employee
{
    char user[31];
    char pass[34];
    uint16_t page;        // Pagina de usuarios
    uint16_t port;        // Puerto por donde es realiza la comunicación
    uint8_t  ip[4];       // Direccion del socket de juego
    uint16_t amount;
    uint16_t cents;
    char nick[9];
    uint8_t already_logged;
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t extension;
};
}

// We need to tell fusion about our employee struct
// to make it a first-class fusion citizen. This has to
// be in global scope.

//[tutorial_employee_adapt_struct
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::employee,
    (char, user[31])
    (char, pass[34])
    (uint16_t, page)
    (uint16_t, port)
    (uint8_t, ip[4])
    (uint16_t, amount)
    (uint16_t, cents)
    (char, nick[9])
    (uint8_t, already_logged)
    (uint8_t, version)
    (uint8_t, extension)
)
//]

namespace client
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Our employee parser
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //[tutorial_employee_parser
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct employee_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        employee_parser() : employee_parser::base_type(start)
        {
            using boost::spirit::qi::ushort_;
            using ascii::char_;

            start %=
                char_ >> ','
                >> char_ >> ','
                >> ushort_ >> ','

                ;
        }

        qi::rule<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type> start;
    };
    //]
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Main program
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int
main()
{
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    std::cout << "\t\tAn employee parser for Spirit...\n\n";
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";

    std::cout
        << "Give me an employee of the form :"
        << "employee{age, \"surname\", \"forename\", salary } \n";
    std::cout << "Type [q or Q] to quit\n\n";

    using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef client::employee_parser<iterator_type> employee_parser;

    employee_parser g; // Our grammar
    std::string str;
    while (getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
            break;

        client::employee emp;
        std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();
        bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, g, space, emp);

        if (r && iter == end)
        {
            std::cout << boost::fusion::tuple_open('[');
            std::cout << boost::fusion::tuple_close(']');
            std::cout << boost::fusion::tuple_delimiter(", ");

            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
            std::cout << "got: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(emp) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But I get this compilation errors and I have no idea how to solve it or how to write the parser

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp:11:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from user.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<const client::employee>’:
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:43:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Sequence> typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<const Sequence>::type boost::fusion::as_vector(const Sequence&) [with Sequence = client::employee]’
user.cpp:140:65:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:27:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct boost::fusion::detail::as_vector<11>’
             type;
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:11:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from user.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/detail/as_vector.hpp:26:12: error: declaration of ‘struct boost::fusion::detail::as_vector<11>’
     struct as_vector;
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp:11:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from user.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<client::employee>’:
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:34:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Sequence> typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<Sequence>::type boost::fusion::as_vector(Sequence&) [with Sequence = client::employee]’
user.cpp:140:65:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:27:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct boost::fusion::detail::as_vector<11>’
             type;
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:11:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from user.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/detail/as_vector.hpp:26:12: error: declaration of ‘struct boost::fusion::detail::as_vector<11>’
     struct as_vector;
            ^
user.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
user.cpp:140:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘as_vector(client::employee&)’
             std::cout << "got: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(emp) << std::endl;
                                                                 ^
user.cpp:140:65: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp:11:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from user.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:34:5: note: template<class Sequence> typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<Sequence>::type boost::fusion::as_vector(Sequence&)
     as_vector(Sequence& seq)
     ^
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:34:5: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:43:5: note: template<class Sequence> typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<const Sequence>::type boost::fusion::as_vector(const Sequence&)
     as_vector(Sequence const& seq)
     ^
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:43:5: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
```

My only need is to have a fixed size struct, that is the reason to use char XXX[31], but I can change this for any declaration with a fixed size.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use `char[]` instead of `std::string`? You're gonna make things very difficult for yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have more than 10 fields. You need raise the default sequence size limit in `fusion/container/vector/limits.hpp`.

Include this before including any boost fusion header (or, any boost header because many libraries may implicitly include it):

```
#define FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE 15
```

Comment: Hi Sehe, thank you for your 2 answers.
About char[] vs std::string: perhaps I'm wrong but I can't get a fixed size struct with a std::string inside, that is the reason to use char[].

About FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE, I'll try in a while, correct me if I'm wrong, but this will solve the compilation error, but the parser still will don't work properly, right?.

Thank you and Regards

Comment: The struct will still be fixed size if you use `std::string`. What is the reason you need it to be "fixed-size"?

Comment: Your parser expression looks like `char_ >> ',' >> char_ >> ',' >> ushort_ >> ','`. It may "work". But I have no idea what you expect it to do. Can you shed the **[X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)** and ask about what you really want to achieve? It seems to me you're /not/ looking for Boost Spirit (but Boost Serialization, perhaps)

Comment: Let me explain a bit more. I can receive the same information in two ways: 1- TCP/IP socket (implemented with Boost.Asio) as a raw structure for this reason I use char[] instead of std::string, 2- Websockets (implemented with Websocket++) as string separated by ",". And you are rigth, I'm not completetly sure about the result of the parser rule because my acknowledge about Spirit it's limited.

Comment: I define the FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE and the example compile now, but I only parse a string like this "m,p,1000,", after parse I get user=m, pass=m, page=1000; but If I get "mm,pp,1000", the parser return false. I try to use repeat in this way "repeat(1,30)[char_]" but I get another compilation error.

Comment: Okay, for the websockets protocol you might want spirit (unless the other side is also C++, in which case I suggest `boost::archive::text_oarchive`). Of course `qi::char_` is documented to parse a single character. What format do you actually want? I could write up a sample

Comment: unfortunately, in the other side I haven't c++, I will receive a format like the struct in the example, my problem is with the first two fields (user and pass),  the format will be something like "user1, pass1, x, y, ...." the user can take up to 30 characters and the password up to 33.

Comment: That still doesn't tell us much about the format. "I will receive a format like the struct". Does that mean _"struct employee
{
    char user[31];
    char pas"..._ etc. (I know, but `user1, pass1, x, y` is also hardly enough)

Comment: If you'd [accept the answer for answering the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and solving your problem, I might write up a grammar that parses the comma-separated business into the struct. Posting that as a separate answer. Maybe you can ask it as a separate question, since it really is a different question

Comment: Hi sehe, I understand your comment about the format, I re-read my comment and is no clear, sorry for that. I read also your last comment but I don't fully understand it, correct me if I'm wrong but my question is no related to the parser, so follow the rules, I need a new question, right ?